# RegExp vcf in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have this structure, and i want to extract only `FN` and `TEL`:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Pepe;Perez;;;
FN:Pepe Perez
TEL;HOME:+549465738283
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Jose;Perez;;;
FN:Jose Perez
TEL;CELL:+549465738284
END:VCARD
```

Like:

```
[
    {name: 'Pepe perez', tel: '+549465738283'},
    {name: 'Jose perez', tel: '+549465738284'}
]
```

I have this code:

```
var file = fs.readFileSync('app/vcards/00003.vcf', 'utf-8');

var p = new RegExp(/(^FN:)(.*)(\n)(TEL;)(.*:)(\+)([0-9]+)/g);

console.log(p.exec(file));
```

But result is `null`

Anybody help me?

Comment: I would split by newlines and check each line, then split on colon etc.

Comment: I think that caret is giving you grief. Check this out: http://regexr.com/3b5qe

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sn86zw12/

Comment: @adeneo please add your comment as answer, it's okey! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really regex, but on request here's a way to manually parse vCard, as I believe that's the easiest to keep track of and modify

```
var file = fs.readFileSync('app/vcards/00003.vcf', 'utf-8');
var arr  = [];
var obj  = {};

file.split("\n").forEach(function(line) {
    if ( line.indexOf('FN') === 0 ) {
        obj.name = line.split(':').pop().trim();
    } else if ( line.indexOf('TEL') === 0 ) {
        obj.tel = line.replace(/[^0-9+]/g,'');
        arr.push(obj);
    } else if ( line.indexOf('END') === 0 ) {
        obj = {};
    }
});
```

```js
var file = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML.trim();
var arr  = [];
var obj  = {};

file.split("\n").forEach(function(line) {
    if ( line.indexOf('FN') === 0 ) {
        obj.name = line.split(':').pop().trim();
    } else if ( line.indexOf('TEL') === 0 ) {
        obj.tel = line.replace(/[^0-9+]/g,'');
        arr.push(obj);
    } else if ( line.indexOf('END') === 0 ) {
        obj = {};
    }
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

```html
<div id="test">
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Pepe;Perez;;;
FN:Pepe Perez
TEL;HOME:+549465738283
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Jose;Perez;;;
FN:Jose Perez
TEL;CELL:+549465738284
END:VCARD
</div>
```

It should also be noted that there is middleware available for this as well

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vcard

it does basically the same thing, splits the lines and looks for `BEGIN` and `END` to get each card etc.

Comment: Thanks! I tried vcard library, but doesn't work with android vcf file

Comment: @brunocascio - strange, I've never used it myself, but it seems to be downloaded a few hundred times, and there's only one issue logged pertaining to something about validation, so I thought it worked? If the code above does what you want, it's a lot less overhead then including an entire plugin anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use `m` as the flag for multi-line instead of using `g` for global. The latter is more useful when doing multiple replacements but doesn't help when you are matching against multiple lines of text.